# Verify if Xcopy did Copy Anything

Tags: powershell, xcopy

i'm trying to in powershell verify if xcopy did copy something.
Thanks for any help.

```
    xcopy /D /S /E "C:\folder1\*.*" "C:\folder2" /y
     IF %CopiedFilesCount% >0  {

       Start-Process C:\folder3\execute.bat

     }



else{
"0 file copied"
}
```

In bat file this code does almost what i wan't. Trying to change "SourceFile" to "SourceFolder" and "DeleteFile" to "execute command or file"

```
    setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "SourceFile=C:\folder1\file2.txt"
set "DeleteFile=test.txt"
set "DestinationDirectory=C:\folder2\"

for /F %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "%SourceFile%" "%DestinationDirectory%" /C /D /Q /Y 2^>nul') do set "CopiedFilesCount=%%I"

if %CopiedFilesCount% GTR 0 del "%DeleteFile%"
```

Comment: I don't believe `xcopy` offers a log function, however, if you're able to use `robocopy` you can use the built in log function e.g `/log:"c:\path to logs files\some log file.txt"`

Comment: It creates log even when did not copy any file. I won't be able to disctint.

Comment: Why are you using xcopy instead of Copy-Item? Now you're using a mixture of cmd and powershell commands which causes extra complexity since you'll have to parse strings. Using Get-Childitem to get a list of files and then copying them with copy-item keeps you in the Powershell way of working by using objects instead of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell will capture the stdout of any command as either a string or an array of strings.

From there you can use regex to capture the file copy count in the $Matches variable that is created by using -match.  Note - the $Matches variable only populates when you pass in a single string.  You can use -match to get the right line from an array, but then you need to match again to get your capture groups. "?" creates a named capture group we can access as a property of $Matches.

```
$result = xcopy /D /S /E "C:\folder1\*.*" "C:\folder2" /y
($results | Where-Object {$_ -match "(\d+) File"}) -match "(?<Count>\d+) File"
if ([int]$Matches.Count -gt 0) {
  # Do Stuff
}
else {
  # Write a message, write to a log, whatever
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
 It's giving else always.

Comment: @alanbr00 I figured out the issue and updated the answer.

Comment: @alanbr00 i added `[int]` in the if evaluation. Regex produces a string since you are matching a string.  I assumed it was smart enough to convert on it's own. : )

Comment: Thanks! It was of great help.